# DirectX 10/11 games crash in fullscreen mode

Tags: technical-issues, windows-8.1, directx-11, directx-10

Recently (something like 1 month ago), all my DirectX 10/11 games started crashing whenever set to launch in fullscreen mode.

My system specs:

- OS: Windows 8.1 x64
- CPU: Intel Core i5-3230M @ 2.66 GHz (dual core with hyperthreading)
- RAM: 4 GB DDR3 @ 800 MHz
- GPU: Nvidia Optimus with Intel HD4000 and Nvidia GeForce GT 740M
- DxDiag file (just in case): http://pastebin.com/1R2UFhy7

Note: Optimus GPU selection was switched from "Autodetect" to "NVIDIA High performance GPU" (rough translation from French).

Examples of affected games:

- AKIBA'S TRIP: Undead & Undressed
- Devil May Cry 4 Special Edition
- Killing Floor 2

Thanks in advance for your answer(s)

Comment: Does it happen in every game? Does it crash instantly, or after some time? Have you tried reinstalling DirectX?

Comment: Do any of those games run in a different resolution than your desktop? Do they crash with "out of memory" error?

Comment: Did it happen after updating your GPU drivers? If so, try to rollback your driver and see if that fixes your problem. To rollback, follow "*Option 2*" in the following instructions:  http://www.nvidia.com/object/notebook_driver_instructions.html

Comment: @DBS: Every DX10/11 game. Almost instantly. Yes, I reinstalled DirectX (June 2010).

Comment: @Chippies: Nope, nothing like that.

Comment: @Nolonar: I updated my drivers around 5 months ago (so that makes it 4 months before the problem).